# Value of Inverse Sine function in Time Series model

Tags: r

I am using a time series approach where I have used sine function in the ARIMA  model, In most of the time series examples inverse of the log that is antilog is used which is 2.718 in value, what about the inverse of the sine function, please help?

Comment: It's `help("asin")`, the arcsin function, the arc whose sine is `x`.

Comment: There is not in general an inverse for all functions - see https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Trig.html for the trigonometric ones.